# Material TextInput Difficult to Identify

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to render a simple TextInput using QML with the following markup:

```
TextInput {
     id: input
     text: "some text box that has no easy way to identify"
     font {
        pointSize: 16
        family: "Segoe UI Light"
     }
}
```

What's actually rendering is this:

[image]

Notice how there is no way to identify the TextInput without the "default text" I've added. I would have expected something like the following (where there is an underline identifying the TextInput)

[image]

Things tried:

1. Isolated Text Input
2. Text Input in a `Pane`
3. Text Input in a Layout

Not exactly sure why it's not rendering correctly.

Comment: I don't think TextInput does this. You just have to add this line separately by anchoring a rectangle with height ~2 to the text input. You can even go ahead and put it in a separate file so you can reuse it as a custom component

Comment: You are absolutely right @splaytreez I was incorrectly using `TextInput` and instead of should have been using `TextField`. Sad times for me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @splaytreez's comment. I was incorrectly using `TextInput` but should have used `TextField`. Hopefully someone else finds this useful; although, I do feel it's a silly mistake.